# google-map msg ( for devlopement purposes only )

Tags: key

I am working on a website containing a simple google map. 
when I open the page this following message appear om my google map .

PS:the pop-up message on the browser is in french language ,it mean =(this page didn’t load google maps correctly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in the way you are including the API script (an extra `?`)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js??key=AIzaSyAZvxb5BAGPyDnBg5uaoB-U3y0se0KeAqo"></script>
```

should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAZvxb5BAGPyDnBg5uaoB-U3y0se0KeAqo"></script>
```

**updated code snippet:**

```js
// necessary variables
var map;
var infoWindow;
var markersData = [];

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(32, -6),
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
  };


  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  // a new Info Window is created
  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  // Event that closes the Info Window with a click on the map
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.close();
  });

  // Finally displayMarkers() function is called to begin the markers creation
  displayMarkers();


}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


// This function will iterate over markersData array
// creating markers with createMarker function
function displayMarkers() {

  // this variable sets the map bounds according to markers position
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  // for loop traverses markersData array calling createMarker function for each marker 
  $.get("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/abdelhakimsalama/3cce25789f00c1b84ccb5b231ec455b7/raw/393220f08a02b962e3e764d2b497b318353828db/gistfile1.txt", function(response) {
    markersData = JSON.parse(response);
    //console.log(response);


    for (var i = 0; i < markersData.length; i++) {

      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(markersData[i].Latitude, markersData[i].Longitude);
      var Route = markersData[i].Route;
      var Secteur = markersData[i].Secteur;
      var Agence = markersData[i].Agence;
      var CodeClient = markersData[i].CodeClient;
      var PrecisionGPS = markersData[i].PrecisionGPS;
      var Latitude = markersData[i].Latitude;
      var Longitude = markersData[i].Longitude;
      var BarCode = markersData[i].BarCode;
      var NomClient = markersData[i].NomClient;
      var PrenomClient = markersData[i].PrenomClient;
      var NumAdresse = markersData[i].NumAdresse;
      var GeoAdresse = markersData[i].GeoAdresse;
      var Tel = markersData[i].Tel;
      var Whatsapp = markersData[i].Whatsapp;
      var NbrFrigo = markersData[i].NbrFrigo;
      //   var FrigosDetails = markersData[i].FrigosDetails;
      var OpenAm = markersData[i].OpenAm;
      var CloseAm = markersData[i].CloseAm;
      var OpenPm = markersData[i].OpenPm;
      var ClosePm = markersData[i].ClosePm;

      createMarker(latlng, Route, Agence, Secteur, CodeClient, PrecisionGPS, Latitude, Longitude, BarCode, PrenomClient, NomClient, NumAdresse, GeoAdresse, Tel, Whatsapp, NbrFrigo, OpenAm, CloseAm, OpenPm, ClosePm);

      // marker position is added to bounds variable
      bounds.extend(latlng);
    }

    // Finally the bounds variable is used to set the map bounds
    // with fitBounds() function
    map.fitBounds(bounds);

  });
}


// This function creates each marker and it sets their Info Window content
function createMarker(latlng, Route, Agence, Secteur, CodeClient, PrecisionGPS, Latitude, Longitude, BarCode, PrenomClient, NomClient, NumAdresse, GeoAdresse, Tel, Whatsapp, NbrFrigo, OpenAm, CloseAm, OpenPm, ClosePm) {

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: latlng,
    title: CodeClient
  });

  // This event expects a click on a marker
  // When this event is fired the Info Window content is created
  // and the Info Window is opened.
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {


    var dicoFrigosDetails = {};


    var HTMLtext = "";
    for (var i = 1; i <= Object.keys(dicoFrigosDetails).length / 4; i++) {
      HTMLtext += '';
    }
    // Creating the content to be inserted in the infowindow
    var iwContent = '<div id="iw_container">' +
      '<div class="iw_title">Code Client : ' + CodeClient +
      '</div>' + // '<div class="iw_content">Précision : ' + PrecisionGPS + 
      '<br />Latitude : ' + Latitude +
      '<br />Longitude : ' + Longitude +
      '<br />Route : ' + Route +
      '<br />Secteur : ' + Secteur +
      '<br />Agence : ' + Agence +
      //'<br />Code-barres : ' + BarCode +
      '<br />prenom de Client : ' + PrenomClient +
      '<br />nom de Client : ' + NomClient +
      '<br />Num Adresse : ' + NumAdresse +
      '<br />GeoAdresse : ' + GeoAdresse +
      '<br />Téléphone : ' + Tel +
      '<br />Whatsapp : ' + Whatsapp +
      '<br />Nbr Frigos : ' + NbrFrigo + HTMLtext +
      '<br />Ouverture Matin : ' + OpenAm +
      '<br />Fermeture Matin : ' + CloseAm +
      '<br />Ouverture après-midi : ' + OpenPm +
      '<br />Fermeture Après-midi : ' + ClosePm +
      //'<br />Ouverture Matin Ven : ' + OpenAmVen +
      //'<br />Fermeture Matin Ven : ' + CloseAmVen +
      //'<br />Ouverture après-midi Ven: ' + OpenPmVen +
      //'<br />Fermeture après-midi Ven: ' + ClosePmVen +
      //'<br />Ouverture Matin Dim : ' + OpenAmDim +
      //'<br />Fermeture Matin Dim : ' + CloseAmDim +
      //'<br />Ouverture après-midi Dim : ' + OpenPmDim +
      //'<br />Fermeture après-midi Dim : ' + ClosePmDim +
      //'<br />IMEI : ' + IMEI + 
      //'<br />Date Passage : ' + Date_Added + 
      '</div>';

    // including content to the Info Window.
    infoWindow.setContent(iwContent);



    // opening the Info Window in the current map and at the current marker location.
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });



}
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  background: gray;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
}

#iw_container .iw_title {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.iw_content {
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<head>

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="animated_favicon1.gif">

  <title>ABC - Map </title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAZvxb5BAGPyDnBg5uaoB-U3y0se0KeAqo"></script>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/map.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <button type="button" id="buttons"><a href="http://localhost/innotech/inc/export.php">Télécharger le fichier de données EXCEL</a></button>
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>


</body>
```